# How can I log all network connection activity with iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'd like to log connections, connection attempts on a single machine. This should include IP, Port and timestamp. This is really just for analytical / security purposes.

How can I achieve this?

There are similar questions, but none that seem to answer this specifically.

Comment: Why do you have to use iptables? Why can't you use a mechanism designed for this purpose like netflow?

Comment: Can you provide a link to it? A diverse set of results get shown for a web search.

Comment: You have a badly defined question, so of-course any answer will be badly defined. Netflow is a standard for logging streams that's been around 10s of years and has many possible tools. You will likely want to google "netflow daemon" to find tools for creating the logs and do a separate search for netflow tools to parse the logs in a way suitable for your needs.

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful, I misread it to be a specific implementation / tool. Not too sure why you think it's a badly defined question / answers though - due to the constraint on iptables? Everything else I came across suggested things like netstat/dtrace/tcpdump hence I tried to be specific.

Comment: Im pleased my comment helped. The main things are that it is an XY problem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem - yes, because of iptables ) and, probably relatedly, fails to identify relevant info like OS, purpose (are you trying to log info about a service or connection or something else, what is being done with the raw data)

Comment: Analytical / security purposes. It's still not clear to me though why iptables is not suited for this problem? Seems sufficient, and seems to be installed by default on most Linux distros I've come across.

Comment: Iptables is not designed with this in mind (its good at firewalling/mangling data, not so much recording/analysing it - I'm fairly sure it doesn't buffer or consolidate streams well), and will likely be slow because of the naive way logging is typically done, and could be/silently become incomplete if rules are prepended which match and accept traffic (which is common). Are you sure something like snort (https://www.snort.org/) is not a better solution - it does logging and intrusion detection.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `ulogd`, which uses the iptables `ULOG` target to receive log events from Netfilter to itself. `ulogd` can be then configured to use several output destinations for data, for example MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.

More information can be found at project [homepage](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following iptable config is required:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix='[networklogging] '
iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix='[networklogging] '
```

The log output goes into `/var/log/kern.log` which could be jumbled up with other things... So referencing: https://askubuntu.com/a/348448/585364

We can log to a explicit file with:

```
cat >/etc/rsyslog.d/00-my_iptables_networklogging.conf <<EOL
:msg,contains,"[networklogging] " -/var/log/iptables_networklogging.log
& stop
EOL
```

We also need to restart rsyslog:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Note this solution is limited and ignores traffic at layer 2 (like ARP)